# Add confusion matrix in naive bayes python code

Tags: python, naivebayes, confusion-matrix

I would like to ask how to add confusion matrix in naive bayes python code.
I got naive bayes code from
  [naive bayes for iris data](http://pastebin.com/sUYm97qi)

i need some change to add confusion matrix.
i have separated code for confusion matrix but i  don't  know where to put this on my code, and i don't know what to replace ??? with what.

```
y_actu = pd.Series(???, name='Actual')
y_pred = pd.Series(???, name='Predicted')
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)

print df_confusion
```

i'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use sklearn's `confusion_matrix` function

```
from sklearn.metrics import  confusion_matrix

y_actu = pd.Series(???, name='Actual')
y_pred = pd.Series(???, name='Predicted')

confusionMatrix = confusion_matrix(y_actu, y_pred)
print(confusionMatrix)
```

[Documentation here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)!

Cheers!